# Why does this union structure cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, unions

I defined a union structure that can switch between a string pointer or a long (this is due to alignment issues). The structure itself looks as follows.

```
enum {H_STRING, H_LONG};
union Tag
{
    std::string *path;
    long id;
};

struct TextureID
{
    Tag tag;
    int type=H_STRING;

    TextureID()
    {
        type = H_STRING;
        tag.path = new std::string("");
    }
    TextureID(const TextureID& TID)
    {
        type = TID.type;
        if(type==H_STRING)
            tag.path = new std::string(*(TID.tag.path));
        else
            tag.id = TID.tag.id;
    }
    ~TextureID()
    {
        delete(tag.path);

    }

    TextureID& operator= (std::string str)
    {delete(tag.path); tag.path = new std::string(str); type=H_STRING; return *this;}
    TextureID& operator= (long val)
    { if(type==H_STRING) delete(tag.path); tag.id = val; type=H_LONG; return *this;}

    operator std::string&()
    {
        if(type == H_STRING)
        {
            return *(tag.path);
        }
    }
};

std::istream inline &operator>> (std::istream& is, TextureID& TID)
{is >> *(TID.tag.path); TID.type = H_STRING; return is;}

std::ostream inline &operator<< (std::ostream& os, TextureID& TID)
{return os << *(TID.tag.path);}
```

Using valgrind I have determined that this data structure, as is, has a memory leak.

The way to verify that this structure is the cause of the memory leak (i.e the reason why I am sure this is the cause and not something else) was to overload all operators currently being used (=, <<, >>) and have two versions of the data structure. the first is the one you see above using the union. the second simply has a string and a long as 2 separate fields in TextureID.

With the second implementation (the one not using pointers) there are no memory leaks.

I am aware this can cause a segmentation fault if the Tag is set to a long.That is not the issue, the issue is that somehow, despite there being an explicite call to delete() the allocated memory is not getting deleted (currently nothing in the program ever sets the tag value to a long so no seg fault occurs either).

EDIT:

It was requested that I provide proof of a memory leak so here it is:

[image]

This version does not cause a memory leak:

```
enum {H_STRING, H_LONG};

struct TextureID
{
    std::string path;
    long ID;
    int type=H_STRING;

    TextureID& operator= (std::string str)
    {path = str;}
    TextureID& operator= (long val)
    {ID = val;}

    operator std::string&()
    {
        if(type == H_STRING)
        {
            return (path);
        }
    }
};

std::istream inline &operator>> (std::istream& is, TextureID& TID)
{is >> TID.path; return is;}

std::ostream inline &operator<< (std::ostream& os, TextureID& TID)
{return os << TID.path;}
```

Comment: note that with modern c++ you can use `alignas(long)` to say "I want this to be aligned like a long" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

Comment: @OlivierSohn you can align as a long (8 bytes) a string (32 bytes)?.

I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Yes, it's explained in the link, you can prefix the member declaration with `alignas(...)`, like : `alignas(long) std::string myString;`

Comment: About the memory leak, can you provide a minimal example of a program (with a main) that exhibits the memory leak?

Comment: `union` it isn't structure. `union`'s size = size of max size element of `union`. And `union` save only one of all items at the moment. Therefore when you change type from H_STRING to H_LONG, you lose pointer to string. It's memory leak

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the leak? The leak may well be caused by code you haven't shown us.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am attempting to generate the MVE right now

Comment: Are you sure valgrind shows a leak and not a potential leak? Maybe a stupid question, but just making sure.

Comment: Also you can make the members private, and add const accessors to ensure that the other parts of the program don't change the members.

Comment: @Cristi it figures under "definitely lost" So i assume it was definitely a loss :p

Comment: @OlivierSohn what is a const accessor?

Comment: @Makogan Your `struct` lacks an assignment operator.  Thus `{TextureID t1; TextureID t2; t1 = t2;}` will be faulty.

Comment: Valgrind does not always catch everything. Since you have not deleted the copy constructor/assignment that may also be playing in. Try putting print statements in constructor/copy constructor/copy assignment/destructor. If all constructions match a destruction valgrind may be missing something. (or there is a completely different bug).

Comment: @Makogan it's a method that is marked `const` (i.e it doesn't modify your members) and returns a member of the class, either by value, or by const reference.

Comment: There is no memory leak in your program. Please provide evidence.

Comment: @Cristi Upon the very last modification (post has been updated) now the mem leak figures under "possibly lost"

Comment: @mfromla how are you so sure?

Comment: @Makogan - Please provide evidence.

Comment: None of your `=` overloads is the assignment operator for `TextureID`.  In addition, you risk deleting an already deleted pointer in the `TextureID()` destructor if you previously called `TextureID& operator= (long val)`.

Comment: I thought `TextureID(const TextureID& TID)` was already defining a copy cosntructor.

Also I am aware of the potential double free if longs are used. I mentioned it in the post. Currently I am jsut trying to understand the source of the mem leak.

Comment: @Makogan The assignment operator is `TextureID& operator=(const TextureID& TID)`.  You do not have one, thus assigning `TextureID`'s will not work as expected.  Also, if a `TextureID` is a member of another class, and an instance of that class was dynamically created and not properly deallocated, the `TextureID` memory would occur indirectly.

Comment: There is no `main` function

Comment: @M.M I am attempting to replicate the mistake, however a plain declaration of the structure doesn't seem to be enough I am currently trying to replicate the useage of the DS in the original program and then eliminate statements as much as possible

Comment: @Makogan which alignment problem were you trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: This data needs to be sent to the GPU for rendering. However I first need to fetch the strings of the textures and then associate to each texture an offset in a texture array.

To prevent having to copy the entire data the idea was to set the offset as soon as a texture was loaded. But this would involve sendin and additional 32 bytes of memory per texture into the GPU for no reason since the string is not needed.

The compromise was thus to send only 8 bytes through the use of a union.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think you were right it seems to have been the absence of the assignment operator

Comment: @Makogan -- In addition to this, none of your overloaded `=` functions returns a value in the second version, even though the functions are declared as returning a value.  Thus the behavior of your program is undefined for the "working" version using a `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I don't have much experience with operator overloading. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: since C++17 you've got [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which will do job better that your code.

Comment: Or if pre C++17, [boost::any](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/any.html) is another option.

Comment: @MarekR Upon reading the documentation of variant I beleive I need to stick to my frankenstein union.

It may not be the prettiest, but my n1 concern here is optimization, and using try catch blocks to determine types will cause an important performance hit when multipolied across hundreds of potential calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in your first code sample is almost certainly in

> ```
> TextureID& operator= (std::string str)
> {delete(tag.path); tag.path = new std::string(str); type=H_STRING; return *this;}
> ```

This ASSUMES that `tag.path` can be deleted.   It will cause undefined behaviour if that isn't true - for example, if `type == H_LONG`.

While it is debatable whether that genuinely causes a leak,  symptoms of undefined behaviour can be anything, including spurious reports of a memory leak from tools like valgrind.

In any event, a simple fix would be to change this operator to check `if(type == H_STRING)` before doing `delete tag.path`.

The second example does not cause a leak, since the `struct` contains the members separately, and the compiler, by default, will ensure the destructor cleans all members up appropriately (invoking destructors, etc).

As noted by PaulMcKenzie in comments, the second example has other issues  that can also cause undefined behaviour (albeit, probably not a memory leak in practice).   I'll leave those issues alone - that's going beyond the question asked.

Comment: Actually, the second example has issues in that the overloaded `=` functions do not return a value when declared to return a value.

Comment: @Paul - sure.    But that won't show up for the OP without a test case in which the caller uses what is returned by those operators.   And, although the result (for the caller) would be undefined, it is less likely to show up as a memory leak, than in the first code.

Comment: Yes, granted a memory leak would more than likely not be the outcome of the undefined behavior if the function was called.  If anything, a seg fault / memory access violation.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
~TextureID()
{
    delete(tag.path);
}
```

`tag.path` is only valid if it was set (ie if you set tag.id its not valid). So you need to make sure that you only call delete if `tag.path` was set.

```
~TextureID()
{
    if (type == H_STRING) {
        delete(tag.path);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read the question entirely? The part `currently nothing in the program ever sets the tag value to a long` rules out this issue I think. But I agree that you have a point.

Comment: This is to prevent a segmentation fault. you are correct this is needed, but this does not solve the issue I am talking about. Which is a memory leak.